# Correct Interpretation of the glmnet Lambda Grid as a Hyperparameter

Tags: r, glmnet

I am reviewing the `glmnet` `lambda` option and am seeing that the results can vary significantly in some circumstances. I'm wondering if the `lambda` option thus acts as a hyperparameter if the user is supplying their own sequence. For example,

```
set.seed(123)
library(glmnet)
data(QuickStartExample)
lambda_grid <- 10 ^ seq(10, -2, length = 100)
x_train <- x[1:80, ]
x_test <- x[81:nrow(x), ]
y_train <- y[1:80, ]
y_test <- y[81:length(y), ]

glmnet_wout_grid <- cv.glmnet(x_train, y_train)
glmnet_w_grid <- cv.glmnet(x_train, y_train, lambda = lambda_grid)
coef_wout_grid <- coef(glmnet_wout_grid, glmnet_wout_grid$lambda.min)
coef_w_grid <- coef(glmnet_w_grid, glmnet_w_grid$lambda.min)
cbind(coef_wout_grid, coef_w_grid)

21 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                      1           1
(Intercept)  0.28723893  0.28777063
V1           1.30847606  1.31061477
V2           .           .         
V3           0.76037051  0.76460443
V4           .           .         
V5          -0.83788432 -0.84351097
V6           0.52460716  0.53006419
V7           .           0.00272228
V8           0.22322033  0.22750694
V9           .           .         
V10          .           .         
V11          0.22479191  0.23364054
V12          .           .         
V13          .           .         
V14         -1.03491845 -1.03663568
V15          .           .         
V16         -0.02880585 -0.03586173
V17         -0.09662661 -0.10366027
V18          .           .         
V19          .           .         
V20         -0.98477356 -0.99124520

glmnet_wout_grid$lambda.min
0.07493556
glmnet_w_grid$lambda.min
0.07054802

wout_grid_predictions <- predict(glmnet_wout_grid,
                                 s = glmnet_wout_grid$lambda.min,
                             newx = as.matrix(x_test))
w_grid_predictions <- predict(glmnet_w_grid,
                          s = glmnet_w_grid$lambda.min,
                              newx = as.matrix(x_test))
# RMSE Without user specified sequence
sqrt(colMeans(y_test - wout_grid_predictions) ^ 2)
0.6386908

# RMSE With user specified sequence
sqrt(colMeans(y_test - w_grid_predictions) ^ 2)
0.6361434
```

Providing a `lambda` sequence seems to determine a less sparse coefficient vector in this scenario. In other cases, I've found that this is also the case. I've also found that providing a `lambda` sequence can provide a better test set error, although the vector may be less sparse. My questions currently are:

1. Is it truly recommended to provide a user-supplied lambda sequence? I've seen this mentioned online but haven't seen it stated in any more legitimate source.
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, what is the recommended sequence? Choosing one arbitrarily seems like you're creating a hyperparameter when trying to perform variable selection automatically.
3. Does a user specified `lambda` sequence necessarily mean a better root mean-squared error on the test set?
4. Is there a method to optimise the `lambda` sequence with `glmnet`?

I understand this is an extreme example and the test error results are not too different, but I have seen this elsewhere and was hoping for further clarification from anyone who had significant knowledge of `glmnet`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is the regularization weight. The larger its value, the more penalized the model is for being complex (size and number of nonzero coefficients). The objective of regularization is to obtain a simpler and more interpretable model and also to render it more robust to overfitting.

In my experience, the default lambda sequence works fine. You might want to use a user defined sequence if you want to close in the optimal lambda range. In a certain sense, it is indeed a hyperparameter, and in theory there is an optimal value for your intended use.

So:

1. It's recommended that you are aware of the meaning of this parameter and how the model selects it. Whether you use the default or not doesn't make a huge difference.
2. You can shorten and refine the sequence if you want.
3. No. But you can tamper with the sequence until it does.
4. Not sure what you mean here.

Cheers!